# How to chain port calls?

Tags: port, elm

```
port createNewDocument: Encode.Value -> Cmd msg 
port printDocument : () -> Cmd msg
createNewDocument: Document -> Task err msg
printDocument: Task err msg
```

i want to chain this `create` and `print` steps, in one step. Because sometimes i need **both one after another** - some other times i need to `create the document` - make `some updates`, then `print`.

```
someCmd: Cmd msg
someCmd = createNewDocument |> Task.andThen (\ what? -> -- what to add here? printDocument ) |> Task.attempt (\ result -> some result handler )
```

how can i chain `port` calls? Because ports return `Cmd msg` not `Task err msg`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this without introducing a message that lives in the middle. Ports are also only unidirectional, so you would need a subscription port to return the value from your external source.

I.e: Your first command triggers a JavaScript function that sends a message via a subscription, and in your `update` function you handle that message by returning the second command.

```
type Msg
    = ...
    | CreateNewDocument Encode.Value
    | PrintDocument Document

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd.model)
update msg model =
    case msg of 
        ...

        CreateNewDocument value ->
            (model, createNewDocument value)

        PrintDocument document -> 
            (model, printDocument document)

sub : Sub Msg
sub = 
   receiveNewDocument PrintDocument
```